# IIS Express will not pick up changes from Partial Views

Tags: asp.net, iis, razor, iis-express

I have updated my partial view and it doesnt seem to get displayed on browser. I have been building my website very smoothly but today I have done a small change to Layout and I couldnt get it seemed on chrome.

I have tried

```
 - ctrl+f5
 - turning off Chrome caching
 - uninstall/install IISEXPRESS
 - restarting everything :)
 - <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" /> in web.config
```

but nothing worked. what else can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you build and published your site? The way asp.net works is that it creates a dll with your code inside. Any change after publish is not going to show unless you rebuild and publish

Comment: If I publish the side, it works. But, If I debug it with IISEXPRESS, it doesnt pick up the changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there are a couple of reasons for this:

1- Caching

2- Not cleaning and building

3- IIS and VS sync issue

For first one you can put this in your dev `web.config`:

```
<staticcontent>
  <clientcache cachecontrolmode="CacheControlNoCache" />
</staticcontent>
```

The second one doesn't require explaining.

And the third one which I've faced before is to close and reopen `VS` which is annoying but works.